# Problem with using cookies to authenticate users

Tags: javascript, cookies

currently I'm learning to become a WebDev and can't figure out what the problem is with my Passport strategy. My website finds the correct user and console.logs it, but every time I click on the login button, it won't redirect me to /secrets; instead, it redirects me to /login. If I make a GET request directly to /secrets, the cookies work, but otherwise, they don't. Any ideas on what the problem might be?

```
import express from "express";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import pg from "pg";
import bcrypt from "bcrypt";
import session from "express-session";
import passport from "passport";
import { Strategy } from "passport-local";


const app = express();
const port = 3000;
const saltRounds = 10;

app.use(session({
  secret:"UDEMYTEACHING",
  resave:false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  cookie:{
    maxAge:1000*60*60*24,
  }
}));

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.static("public"));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

const db = new pg.Client({
  user: "xxxx",
  host: "xxxx",
  database : "xxxx",
  password: "xxxx",
  port:5432,

});
db.connect();

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.render("home.ejs");
});

app.get("/login", (req, res) => {
  res.render("login.ejs");
  console.log(req.user);
});

app.get("/register", (req, res) => {
  res.render("register.ejs");
});

app.get("/logout", (req, res) => {
  req.logout(function (err) {
    if (err) {
      return next(err);
    }
    res.redirect("/");
  });
});

app.get("/secrets", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.user);
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    res.render("secrets.ejs");
  } else {
    res.redirect("/login");
  }
});

app.post(
  "/login",
  passport.authenticate("local", {
    successRedirect: "/secrets",
    failureRedirect: "/login",
  })
);

app.post("/register", async (req, res) => {
  const email = req.body.username;
  const password = req.body.password;

  try {
    const checkResult = await db.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = $1", [
      email,
    ]);

    if (checkResult.rows.length > 0) {
      req.redirect("/login");
    } else {
      bcrypt.hash(password, saltRounds, async (err, hash) => {
        if (err) {
          console.error("Error hashing password:", err);
        } else {
          const result = await db.query(
            "INSERT INTO users (email, password) VALUES ($1, $2) RETURNING *",
            [email, hash]
          );
          const user = result.rows[0];
          req.login(user, (err) => {
            console.log("success");
            res.redirect("/secrets");
          });
        }
      });
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
});

passport.use(
  new Strategy(async function verify(username, password, cb) {
    try {
      const result = await db.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = $1 ", [
        username,
      ]);
      if (result.rows.length > 0) {
        const user = result.rows[0];
        const storedHashedPassword = user.password;
        bcrypt.compare(password, storedHashedPassword, (err, valid) => {
          if (err) {
            //Error with password check
            console.error("Error comparing passwords:", err);
            return cb(err);
          } else {
            if (valid) {
              //Passed password check
              return cb(null, user);
            } else {
              //Did not pass password check
              return cb(null, false);
            }
          }
        });
      } else {
        return cb("User not found");
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  })
);

passport.serializeUser((user, cb) => {
  cb(null, user.id); // Verwenden Sie die eindeutige ID des Benutzers hier
});

passport.deserializeUser(async (id, cb) => {
  try {
    const result = await db.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = $1", [id]);
    const user = result.rows[0];
    cb(null, user);
  } catch (err) {
    cb(err);
  }
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`);
});
```

Perhaps someone can help and explain why the cookies are not working as they are supposed to. I believe it's crucial to understand the intricacies of cookies. Nonetheless, I could just use OAuth to authenticate users instead of handling it locally.